# JavaScript object property display issue

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to make a basic calculation system here and when I make a calculation, for example I enter `1,1` into the first prompt and then `add` into the second prompt, which, through my `switch`, calls `things.add(1,1)`, they work in console but the final result is not being displayed as expected in terms of printing out the calculation result within my `document.write`.

```
var nums = prompt("please enter the numbers you wish to calculate separated by a comma. eg 1,3").split(",").map(function(t){return parseFloat(t);});
var choice = prompt("what do you wish to do with the numbers: "+nums +" your choices are: add, subtract, multiply, divide").toLowerCase();

var things = {
total: 0,
getTotal: function getTotal() {
    return this.total;
},
add: function add(a, b) {
    this.total = parseFloat(a + b);
},
subtract: function add(a, b) {
    this.total = parseFloat(a - b);
    console.log(things.total);
},
multiply: function add(a, b) {
    this.total = parseFloat(a * b);
    console.log(things.total);
},
divide: function add(a, b) {
    this.total = parseFloat(a / b);
    console.log(things.total);
},
};
document.write("<h3>Calculations</h3><br>");
document.write("<p>you have elected to "+choice +" the numbers "+nums[0]+" and "+nums[1]+"</p>");
document.write("<p>the answer is: " + things.getTotal()+"</p>");
switch(choice) {
case 'add':
    things.add(nums[0],nums[1]);
    break;
case 'multiply':
    things.multiply(nums[0],nums[1]);
    break;
case 'subtract':
    things.subtract(nums[0],nums[1]);
    break;
case 'divide':
    things.divide(nums[0],nums[1]);
    break;
default:
    console.log("nothing entered!");
    break;
}
```

I am not sure if I have used all the correct terminology here, as I'm still learning but I hope you can see the issue without getting hung up on if I've accidentally called a method an object or whatever the case may be. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be helpful to include examples of input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting `things.getTotal()` before the calculation actually happened. Move the switch statement above the three `document.write()` statements and it should work.

Comment: ugh I feel very silly right about now. Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

Print the value(`document.write("<p>the answer is: " + things.getTotal()+"</p>");`) after the calculation
https://jsfiddle.net/jd28o6sh/

Comment: Thanks for the post, was indeed the issue as lex82 pointed out also.